# Hide specific text with jquery on mouseover

Tags: jquery, html, css, mouseover

I can't seem to get this to work:

```
$('.products-grid li').hover(
function(){
    $('.price').html().replace('DKK','');
});
```

I want the "DKK" to not show, when the mouse is over the list-item.
I know I can do this by adding a span around the DKK, but this is not possible for me to do so. I'm locked within the setup of the HTML as you see it here.

http://jsfiddle.net/4UeMd/

Hope someone can help me.
This might be a simple jQuery coding I'm missing, but I can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call .html() twice, once to get the string and once to set it.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/tkduT/)

```
$('.products-grid li').hover(function () {
    $('.price').html($('.price').html().replace('DKK', ''));
});
```

Your code `$('.price').html().replace('DKK','');` was getting the text on each `.price` element, replacing the text and returning it to nothing.

---

To get DKK back when you leave the element you can do this, you also want to target `.price` not `li`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/tkduT/5/)

```
$('.products-grid .price').hover(function () {
    $(this).each(function () {
        var me = $(this);
        me.html(me.html().replace('DKK', ''));
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).each(function () {
        var me = $(this);
        me.html(me.html() + 'DKK');
    });
});
```

Comment: And how do I get the DKK back, when leaving the list-item?

Comment: Updated, they don't change now. Need to use an `$.each` or `for`.

Comment: Even closer - now it just has to work on the one list-item, and not all at once. :)
See here, what i mean? http://jsfiddle.net/tkduT/3/

Comment: Updated, we target `.price` instead of `li`.

Comment: You'll notice some flickering if you hover DKK, you can get around this by setting `.price {display:block;}` http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/tkduT/6/

Comment: But if we target price, it's only on the mouseover on the .price, not mouseover on the list-item. And that's where i need it to be ;)

Comment: Neveermind, i figured it out. Thanks for guiding me in the right direction.
Final solution: http://jsfiddle.net/tkduT/7/

Answer (score 1):

Set the `html` of the element in the script.  Currently the script just modifies the innerHtml of `.price` it does not set the `html` of price.

```
$('.products-grid li').hover(
    function(){
        $('.price').html($('.price').html().replace('DKK',''));
    });
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/4UeMd/5/

Answer (score 0):

Here is small code for hint :

```
abcd xyz <label class='txt'>DDK</label>dbs ksbdh ksjdk <label class='txt'>DDK</label>
```

write following script  onmouse over function:

```
$('.txt').hide(300);
```

Comment: As i said - i can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to set the html with the replced version
2. You need to use .each to do it for all the .price in order to apply it correctly

   ```
   $('.products-grid li').mouseover(function(){
   $('.price').each(function(){
       var replaced = $(this).html().replace('DKK','');
       $(this).html(replaced);
   });
   ```

   });